# Angular + RequireJS app gives error "mainController not a function"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

Okay this is the situation. I'm trying to build an `AngularJS` app from scratch, and I'm combining it with `RequireJS`. This is where it all goes down hill.

What happens is that I get an error saying that `mainController is not a function got undefined`. But some time, just for a second I can see a message in my `Console.log` in the browser telling me some informations from the controller, just before the error shows.

How can this be?

As I said I'm in uncharted territory and I have no idea where to look, so I'm just gonna give you guys what files I have ^^

**Brace yourself code is coming**

File tree

[image]

app/modules/main.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        //  Load dependencies
        'angular': '../lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular.min',
        'angular-route': '../lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular-route.min',

        //  Load modules
        'app': '../app/modules/core/app'
    },
    shim: {
        'angular-route': {
            deps: ['angular']
        },
        'app': {
            deps: ['angular-route']
        }
    }
});

require(['app'], function () {
    //  The application has been loaded
});
```

app/modules/core/app.js

```
define(function () {
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'app/modules/core/views/home.html',
                controller: 'homeController'
            })
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: 'app/modules/core/views/home.html',
                controller: 'homeController'
            });
    }]);

    require(['../app/modules/core/controllerReferences'], function (references) {
        require(references, function () { 
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
        });
    })
});
```

app/modules/core/controllerReferences.js

```
define(function () {
    return [
        'modules/core/controllers/mainController',
        'modules/core/controllers/homeController'
    ];
});
```

app/modules/core/controllers/mainController.js

```
define(function () {
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        console.log('mainController at your service');
    }]);
});
```

**EDIT**

The error which I recieve

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/ng/areq?p0=mainController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:3644/lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular.min.js:6:416
    at qb (http://localhost:3644/lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular.min.js:22:131)
    at Sa (http://localhost:3644/lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular.min.js:22:218)
    at http://localhost:3644/lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular.min.js:80:81
    at O (http://localhost:3644/lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular.min.js:59:501)
    at K (http://localhost:3644/lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular.min.js:60:338)
    at g (http://localhost:3644/lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular.min.js:54:410)
    at g (http://localhost:3644/lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular.min.js:54:433)
    at g (http://localhost:3644/lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular.min.js:54:433)    
(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:107
(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:80
n.$apply @ angular.min.js:133
(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:20
e @ angular.min.js:39
d @ angular.min.js:19
zc @ angular.min.js:20
(anonymous function) @ app.js:18
context.execCb @ require.js:1678
Module.check @ require.js:878
(anonymous function) @ require.js:1128
(anonymous function) @ require.js:131
(anonymous function) @ require.js:1178
each @ require.js:56
Module.emit @ require.js:1177
Module.check @ require.js:929
Module.enable @ require.js:1165
Module.init @ require.js:783
callGetModule @ require.js:1192
context.completeLoad @ require.js:1571
context.onScriptLoad @ require.js:1699
```

Comment: Hm, could you provide more information on the error? Usually if an error is being thrown you'll get the file, line number, and stack trace.

Comment: I sure can, just updated the question ^^

Comment: Done. Originally I had thought you had a reference (in your HTML) to an undefined controller, but obviously that made no sense seeing as the names matched and you had output in the console. Was an interesting problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in your controller definitions.

`var app = angular.module('app', []);` creates a new module
`var app = angular.module('app');` retrieves an existing module

So your `mainController.js` should look like this:

```
define(function () {
    var app = angular.module('app');

    app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        console.log('mainController at your service');
    }]);
});
```

Basically, what you were doing was creating your `app` module three times- once in the beginning, and twice more when you included your controllers.

See [this question](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap) for more info.